# Is it correct to say "I feel terrible"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I was told that we shouldn't say "I feel painful" and should say "I feel pain". Because "I feel painful" sounds like I cause the pain. If I want to express that I experience a physical feeling of pain, I should say "I feel pain". 
But can I say "I feel terrible" to mean that I experience a physical feeling of extreme sadness? Wouldn't it sound like I cause that extreme sadness? It seems quite common to hear people say "I feel terrible". I am just wondering why "I feel terrible" is OK but "I feel painful" is NOT OK.

Comment: "I feel terrible" is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: You would say "I feel pain" but not painful. A cut in the skin is painful. It is also most common to feel terrible *for* someone or their problems. Someone here will give an answer with the part of speech that pain and painful encompass.

Comment: "Feel" can be a linking verb (copula), that is it can take a subject complement. With "I feel painful," painful links to the subject, so the meaning is "I am filled with pain." With "I feel pain," pain is the object of the verb (this time feel functions as a transitive verb), comparable to "I feel a hot stove."  With "I feel terrible," feel again functions as a linking verb. All three sentences are common.

Comment: _I feel terrible_ can mean that you feel either very sad or very ill. (Here, _terrible_ means _very bad_, not its original sense of _causing terror_.) You can say 'My shoulder feels painful', but it is not idiomatic to say 'I feel painful' - we say 'I am in pain.'

Comment: Thank you all. Your comments are really helpful.